# Simply, I want to get Mobile Number and show it to textView in android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, phone-number

Simply, I want to retrieve Mobile Number and show it to textView in android Studio?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.getLine1Number();


}
```

Comment: Using question mark doesn't make a question from every sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have this permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> '
```

Then use this code to put the number in a `TextView`

```
TextView phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
phone.setText(tm.getLine1Number());
```

Of course, make sure that your layout `activity_main` has a textview with the ID `phoneNumber`, or whatever you want to use.

Comment: where to permisssion implement and how to able show number i=on screen.. i m unable get your point please guide me .. thanx!

Comment: The permission should go inside `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the `<manifest>` tag. I'm not sure what you mean by the second part of your question